# How to get pgp's scdaemon on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: package-management, security, gnupg, signature

How to get pgp's scdaemon on ubuntu 18.04? It seems that for older versions it is present, but how should I install for newer ones?

PS: I'm trying to use `gpg --edit-card`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can search for packages using `apt search`:

```
apt search scdaemon
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
scdaemon/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 2.2.4-1ubuntu1.1 amd64
  GNU privacy guard - smart card support
```

in your case the package you are looking for is [called `scdaemon`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/scdaemon), so you can simple install it by:

```
sudo apt install scdaemon  # Smartcard daemon for the GnuPG system
```

Comment: I remember not being able to find it in ubuntu 18.04 live image (I did apt update before)

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs That's because it's a 'universe' package - the Live Images don't by default enable Universe during the live session.  It's not part of Main so it's not default-included - you can always enable the Universe repos to find it.